# Trouble outputting model data dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create some divs out of my view model using jQuery. This is the code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.MemberProfiles));
    console.log(model);

    for (profile in model) {
        $("#viewMembers").append("<div class='profilePreview'><p>" + profile["FirstName"] + "</p></div>");
    }

    $("#viewMembersBtn").click(function () {
        $("#viewMembers").toggle();
    });
});
```

As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drX1L.png), the "FirstName" property evaluates to undefined. If you look at the console.log() in this same image, the objects have the correct data. How do I retrieve the FirstName property correctly?

Comment: Try **not** to send **functions** with your JSON.

Comment: It needs to be `profile.FirstName` assuming `MemberProfiles` is `IEnumerable<T>` (you need to show your model)

Comment: But why in the world are you using javascript to do this instead of just using a razor `@foreach(var item in Model.MemberProfiles) { ...`?

Comment: Oh... good point. I'm new. @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `model[profile].FirstName`:

```
for (var profile in model) {
    $("#viewMembers").append("<div class='profilePreview'><p>" + model[profile].FirstName + "</p></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to access your JavaScript Model like this:

```
 for (profile in model) {
    $("#viewMembers").append("<div class='profilePreview'><p>" + profile.FirstName + "</p></div>");
}
```

Comment: This is actually how I was accessing the property initially. I changed it square-bracket syntax while attempting to fix it. The first name still prints as "undefined". :(